# getting my ovals to stack up on each column

Tags: java, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [issue with my main method in my connect4 game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025055/issue-with-my-main-method-in-my-connect4-game)

Hi,
on my connect4 game, whenever i click on any square it places the oval on that specific square, how do i get it so that it places the oval on the lowest square in that column so that it can stack up?

```
package Game;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ConnectFourBoard {

    // This constant is used to indicate the width and height, in cells,
    // of the board.  Since we want an 8x8 board, we'll set it to 8.
    private static final int WIDTH = 8;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 8;
    private ConnectFourCell[][] currentPlayer;

    // The current state the Othello board is defined with these two
    // fields: a two-dimensional array holding the state of each cell,
    // and a boolean value indicating whether it's the black player's
    // turn (true) or the white player's turn (false).
    private ConnectFourCell[][] cells;
    private boolean isBlueTurn;

    // Since the board is a model and it needs to notify views of changes,
    // it will employ the standard "listener" mechanism of tracking a list
    // of listeners and firing "events" (by calling methods on those
    // listeners) when things change.
    private ArrayList<ConnectFourListener> listeners;

    public ConnectFourBoard()
    {
        // Arrays, in Java, are objects, which means that variables of
        // array types (like cells, which has type OthelloCell[][]) are
        // really references that say where an array lives.  By default,
        // references point to null.  So we'll need to create an actual
        // two-dimensional array for "cells" to point to.
        cells = new ConnectFourCell[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
        listeners = new ArrayList<ConnectFourListener>();
        reset();
        isBlueTurn = true; 

    }

    public void reset(){
        for (int i = 0; i<WIDTH ; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j<HEIGHT; j++){

                cells[i][j] = ConnectFourCell.NONE; 
            }
        }

        isBlueTurn = true; 
    }

    public void addConnectFourListener(ConnectFourListener listener)
    {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }


    public void removeConnectFourListener(ConnectFourListener listener)
    {
        if (listeners.contains(listener))
        {
            listeners.remove(listener);
        }
    }


    // These are fairly standard "fire event" methods that we've been building
    // all quarter, one corresponding to each method in the listener interface.

    private void fireBoardChanged()
    {
        for (ConnectFourListener listener : listeners)
        {
            listener.boardChanged();
        }
    }


    private void fireGameOver()
    {
        for (ConnectFourListener listener : listeners)
        {
            listener.gameOver();
        }
    }


    // isBlackTurn() returns true if it's the black player's turn, and false
    // if it's the white player's turn.
    public boolean isBlueTurn()
    {
        return isBlueTurn;
    }

    public int getWidth()
    {
        return WIDTH;


    }

    public int getHeight(){

        return HEIGHT; 
    }
    // getBlackScore() calculates the score for the black player.
    public int getBlackScore()
    {
        return getScore(ConnectFourCell.BLUE);
    }


    // getWhiteScore() calculates the score for the white player.
    public int getWhiteScore()
    {
        return getScore(ConnectFourCell.RED);
    }

    // getScore() runs through all the cells on the board and counts the
    // number of cells that have a particular value (e.g., BLACK or WHITE).
    // This method uses the naive approach of counting them each time
    // it's called; it might be better to keep track of this score as we
    // go, updating it as tiles are added and flipped.
    private int getScore(ConnectFourCell cellValue)
    {
        int score = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++)
            {
                if (cells[i][j] == cellValue)
                {
                    score++;
                }
            }
        }

        return score;
    }




    // getWhiteScore() calculates the score for the white player.
    public int getRedScore()
    {
        return getScore(ConnectFourCell.RED);
    }

    public int getBlueScore() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getScore(ConnectFourCell.BLUE);
    }


    public ConnectFourCell getCell(int x, int y)
    {
        if (!isValidCell(x, y))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "(" + x + ", " + y + ") is not a valid cell");
        }

        return cells[x][y];
    }
    /**
    * The drop method.
    *
    * Drop a checker into the specified HEIGHT,
    * and return the WIDTH that the checker lands on.
    */
    int drop(int HEIGHT) {
    if (hasWon()) {
    return -1;
    }

    for ( ; WIDTH<6 && HEIGHT != 0; WIDTH++) { };

    if (WIDTH==6) {
    // if the WIDTH is 6, it went through all 6 WIDTHs
    // of the cells, and couldn't find an empty one.
    // Therefore, return false to indicate that this
    // drop operation failed.
    return -1;
    }
    // fill the WIDTH of that HEIGHT with a checker.
    cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH] = currentPlayer[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
    // alternate the players
    //currentPlayer = (currentPlayer%2)+1;
    return WIDTH;
    }
    /**
    * The toString method
    *
    * Returns a String representation of this
    * Connect Four (TM) game.
    */
    public String toString() {
    String returnString = "";
    for (int WIDTH=5; WIDTH>=0; WIDTH--) {
    for (int HEIGHT=0; HEIGHT<7; HEIGHT++) {
    returnString = returnString + cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
    }
    returnString = returnString + "\n";
    }
    return returnString;
    }
    /**
    * The hasWon method.
    *
    * This method returns true if one of the
    * players has won the game.
    */
    public boolean hasWon()

    {
            // First, we'll establish who the current player and the opponent is.
        //ConnectFourCell



        ConnectFourCell myColor =
                isBlueTurn() ? ConnectFourCell.BLUE : ConnectFourCell.RED;

        ConnectFourCell otherColor =
                isBlueTurn() ? ConnectFourCell.RED : ConnectFourCell.BLUE;


    return true;

    }

    public void validMove( ){

    }
    public void makeAMove(int x, int y){

        //System.out.println(x+" "+y);
    //  cells[x][y] = ConnectFourCell.BLUE;

        //Check who's turn it is.  Set to that color.
        ConnectFourCell myColor = null;
        if ( isBlueTurn == true){
            myColor = myColor.BLUE; 

        }
        else {
            myColor = myColor.RED; 
        }

        cells[x][y]  = myColor; 


        //Check if it's a valid move.  If there is a piece there. can't
        // Look at the column.  play piece in the highest available slot



        //Check if there are 4 in a row.
        for (int WIDTH=0; WIDTH<6; WIDTH++) {
            for (int HEIGHT=0; HEIGHT<4; HEIGHT++) {
            if (!(cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH] == ConnectFourCell.NONE)  &&
            cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH] == cells[HEIGHT+1][WIDTH] &&
            cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH] == cells[HEIGHT+2][WIDTH] &&
            cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH] == cells[HEIGHT+3][WIDTH]) {

            }
            }
            }
            // check for a vertical win
            for (int WIDTH=0; WIDTH<3; WIDTH++) {
            for (int HEIGHT=0; HEIGHT<7; HEIGHT++) {
            if (!(cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH] == ConnectFourCell.NONE)  &&
            cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH] == cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH+1] &&
            cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH] == cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH+2] &&
            cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH] == cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH+3]) {

            }
            }
            }
            // check for a diagonal win (positive slope)
            for (int WIDTH=0; WIDTH<3; WIDTH++) {
            for (int HEIGHT=0; HEIGHT<4; HEIGHT++) {
                if (!(cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH] == ConnectFourCell.NONE) &&
            cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH] == cells[HEIGHT+1][WIDTH+1] &&
            cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH] == cells[HEIGHT+2][WIDTH+2] &&
            cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH] == cells[HEIGHT+3][WIDTH+3]) {

            }
            }
            }
            // check for a diagonal win (negative slope)
            for (int WIDTH=3; WIDTH<6; WIDTH++) {
            for (int HEIGHT=0; HEIGHT<4; HEIGHT++) {
                if (!(cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH] == ConnectFourCell.NONE)  &&
            cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH] == cells[HEIGHT+1][WIDTH-1] &&
            cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH] == cells[HEIGHT+2][WIDTH-2] &&
            cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH] == cells[HEIGHT+3][WIDTH-3]) {

            }
            }
            }


        fireBoardChanged();
        isBlueTurn = !isBlueTurn;

    }

    private boolean isValidCell(int x, int y)
    {
        return x >= 0 && x < WIDTH
              && x>= 0 && x<HEIGHT
              && y >= 0 && y < WIDTH
              && y>= 0 && y<HEIGHT;
    }
}


package UI;



import java.awt.*; 


import javax.swing.*;

import UI.ConnectFourBoardPanel;

import Game.ConnectFourBoard;
import Game.ConnectFourListener;

public class ConnectFourFrame extends JFrame implements ConnectFourListener {

    // Variables

    private ConnectFourBoard board;

    private JLabel scoreLabel;
    private ConnectFourBoardPanel boardPanel;
    private JLabel statusLabel;


    public ConnectFourFrame()
    {
        // The frame builds its own model.
         board = new ConnectFourBoard(); 

        // We want the frame to receive notifications from the board as its
        // state changes.
        System.out.println(this);
        board.addConnectFourListener(this);

        setTitle("Informatics 45 Spring 2011: ConnectFour Game");
        setSize(700, 700);
        setResizable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        buildUI();
        refreshUI();
    }


    private void buildUI()
    {
        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);

        Font labelFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 18); 

        scoreLabel = new JLabel();
        scoreLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        scoreLabel.setFont(labelFont);
        layout.setConstraints(
            scoreLabel,
            new GridBagConstraints(
                0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,
                new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10), 0, 0));
        getContentPane().add(scoreLabel);

        boardPanel = new ConnectFourBoardPanel(board);
        layout.setConstraints(
            boardPanel,
            new GridBagConstraints(
                0, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10), 0, 0));
        getContentPane().add(boardPanel);

        statusLabel = new JLabel();
        statusLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        statusLabel.setFont(labelFont);
        layout.setConstraints(
            statusLabel,
            new GridBagConstraints(
                0, 2, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,
                new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10), 0, 0));
        getContentPane().add(statusLabel);
    }

    private void refreshUI()
    {
        // Refreshing the UI means to change the text in each of the
        // two labels (the score and the status) and also to ask the
        // board to repaint itself.

        scoreLabel.setText(
            "Blue: " + board.getBlueScore() +
            "          Red: " + board.getRedScore());



                if ( board.isBlueTurn() == false){
                    statusLabel.setText("Blue's Turn: ");
                }
                if ( board.isBlueTurn() == true){
                    statusLabel.setText("Red's Turn: ");
                }


        boardPanel.repaint();
    }

    // These are the ConnectFourBoardListener event-handling methods.

    public void boardChanged()
    {
        // When the board changes, we'll refresh the entire UI.  (There
        // are times when this approach is too inefficient, but it will
        // work fine for our relatively simple UI.)

        refreshUI();
    }


    public void gameOver()
    {
        // When the game is over, we'll pop up a message box showing the final
        // score, then, after the user dismisses the message box, dispose of
        // this window and end the program.

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            this,
            "Game over!\nFinal score: " + scoreLabel.getText(),
            "Game Over",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        dispose();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.  You're question is fine - but pasting your whole program, in general, is a bad idea.  You should describe your program, and include the snippet where you calculate how the ovals are filled in.

Having said that, here's a crack at the answer :
  - You want to look at the tile thats currently selected, and if the tile underneath it is occupied, fill in that cell.  If its not occupied, set the current tile to the underneath tile, and repeat.  You want to do this until you get to the bottom row.

The answer above doesn't incude checking if the selected tile is already occupied, but I'm sure you can easily figure that out.

Comment: He's been told this several times before -- he's not new here, but he never responds and never improves.